# Cameras watching each other in art gallery

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, computational-geometry

I am trying to prove the following:

> Let $c(n)$ be the minimum number of cameras, where each is seen by at least one other camera. Now $c(n)$ is always sufficient and sometimes necessary for watching an $n$-walled gallery which is orthogonal. Prove that $c(n)$ is equal to $\left \lfloor{\dfrac{n}{e}}\right \rfloor$.

I know of the art gallery problems and that for an orthogonal polygon, only $\left \lfloor{\dfrac{n}{4}}\right \rfloor$ guards are needed. 
I have not been able to figure out how to prove this problem. More specifically, I am not sure where or how the $e$ comes in to play.

I would appreciate some hints/guidance on this. Thank you.

Comment: No idea if it's related (in fact, I doubt it), but this reminds me of the formula for derangements, just with $n$ instead of $n!$.